# How do I get parameters from a PHP Object?

Tags: php, api, rest, object

The object is contained in $response.

```
echo "<pre>";
 print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";
```

.. gives me the following:

```
Att\Api\Speech\SpeechResponse Object
(
   [_responseId:Att\Api\Speech\SpeechResponse:private] => f4119dcd51929c2dfae5e2d746c1d9a1
   [_status:Att\Api\Speech\SpeechResponse:private] => OK
   [_NBest:Att\Api\Speech\SpeechResponse:private] => Att\Api\Speech\NBest Object
        (
            [_hypothesis:Att\Api\Speech\NBest:private] => hi how are you
            [_languageId:Att\Api\Speech\NBest:private] => en-US
            [_confidence:Att\Api\Speech\NBest:private] => 0.5
            [_grade:Att\Api\Speech\NBest:private] => accept
            [_resultText:Att\Api\Speech\NBest:private] => Hi how are you.
            [_words:Att\Api\Speech\NBest:private] => Array
                (
                  [0] => Hi
                  [1] => how
                  [2] => are
                  [3] => you.
                )

            [_wordScores:Att\Api\Speech\NBest:private] => Array
                (
                  [0] => 0.33
                  [1] => 1
                  [2] => 1
                  [3] => 1
                )

        )

    )
```

N00b question: How would I now be able to receive the value from **_resultText**?

Comment: Should be something like $response->getNBest()->getResultText() ?

Answer (score 1):

A good question on a broader level but one that could be answered easily by the manual for that Class itself.

**[RTM](https://github.com/attdevsupport/codekit-php/blob/master/lib/Speech/NBest.php)**

```
print_r($response->getNBest()->getResultText());
```

Comment: You forgot getNBest, OP is in Speech object